# Kafka - Ignoring fetched records

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, kafka-consumer-api

My Kafka consumer is reading messages from a Kafka topic named `testdata`. The consumer is a Apache Flink source connector.

When I send a new message to the topic, the consumer doesn't fetch the message. In debug log I can see the following message:

```
Ignoring fetched records for testdata at offset 0 since the current position is 1
```

It seems that my consumer has always the wrong offset? What can I do to get the messages from that topic?

**UPDATE:**

I tried a lot of configuration with offset settings. I also cleared all tmp files with offset information for Kafka and Zookeeper. But nothing changed. Current position is always one number ahead of the offset.

What does the debug log line exactly mean?

```
Ignoring fetched records for testdata at offset 141 since the current position is 142
```

Comment: Try setting the group.id of the consumer to something different or a random UUID. Also try setting the auto.offset.reset property to earliest.

Comment: Relevant link that explains this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6088

Answer (score 0):

Please set `enable.auto.commit=false`